# I want to connect my Drupal site with facebook app

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, facebook-javascript-sdk, drupal-8

I want to connect my Drupal site with facebook app. When i am trying put this url http://10.30.20.60 in site url in facebook app it is giving error as This can't be a Facebook URL . so can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do wanting to connect with facebook? 
There are several drupal modules that allow various levels of integration with facebook. You should give this a read:
https://groups.drupal.org/node/65268

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the final url of your site, the internet url.
10.30.20.60 is a local URL that s why Facebook doesn't allow you to create an app for this url.